# Setting Default Write permissions for group in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

How can i achieve the following behaviour;
If user1, which is in group2 creates directories or files, the group should have write permissions by default on this files/directories. I already tried putting umask 002 in /home/user1/.profile and .bashrc but this gave me the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user1 group2  4096 Aug  3 11:17 test1
```

So how can i achieve this? The change should  be persistent, even after reboot etc.

Comment: `.profile` is not read by `bash`, which is the default shell for almost all Linux distros. You should use `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: i already tried it for .bashrc. Shoulhd have mentioned it :) Edited my question...

Comment: Have you tried `.bash_profile` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it with ACL.

```
setfacl -R -dm g:group2:rw /something
setfacl -R -m g:group2:rw /something
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Just got it working a week ago exactly like this. Forgot to post the solution :)